# Xamarin Release Build Archirecture

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I recently Updated the VS for Mac. After Wards I cannot Select Build Architecture Armv7 + arm64. It allows Arm64 alone. Since my app is not going to be pushed in App Store i do want these s=architecture to be selected as my build configuration. How to sorted out this

Comment: You would need to use an older version of Xcode and Xamarin.iOS, Armv7 support was dropped by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually edit .csproj file and write whatever value you want.

Comment: Thanks. It throws a build error if amr7 presented in .csproject

Comment: @Muthukumar then it is not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

Apple deprecated 32 bit support in iOS 11. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios11/updating-your-app/architecture-changes

32-bit apps will not launch in iOS 11+ and we actually can't compile the 32 bit slice with newer Xcode. This is why you can't just edit the csproj, you'd need Xcode 9.4 for that.

Even if you don't deploy to the store you shouldn't have any issue with a 64 bit only App.